# Не могу разобраться с GETDATA SET DATA rage C#

Tags: c#

столкнулся с проблемой, нужна Ваша помощь!
Не могу понять синтаксис **Player.GetData** :(

Собственно
Посмотрите на всякий, скриншоты, так же прикрепил код, подскажите и немного объясните пожалуйста:)

Server.cs

```
[ServerEvent(Event.PlayerConnected)] //- IT`S WORK! (больше не крашит ебана рот Server.exe !)
    public void OnPlayerConnected(Player Player)
    {
        NAPI.Util.ConsoleOutput($"{Player.Name} присоеденился");
        MyServer.Data.Data player = new MyServer.Data.Data(Player);
        Player.SetData(MyServer.Data.Data.DataIndetifier, player);
    }
///
[ServerEvent(Event.PlayerSpawn)]
    public void OnPlayerSpawn(Player player)
    {
        if (Player.HasData(MyServer.Data.Data.DataIndetifier))
        {
            var player = Player.GetData(MyServer.Data.Data.DataIndetifier);
            NAPI.Player.SetPlayerHealth(player, 50);                                                                                                     // NAPI.Player.SetPlayerHealth(player,50);
        }
    }
```

Data.cs

```
 class Data
{
    public static readonly String DataIndetifier = "PlayerInfo";
    public Player PlayerData { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
 public Data(Player player)
    {
        this.PlayerData = player;
        this.Name = player.Name;
    }
}
```

[image: Server.cs]
[image: Data.cs]

Comment: Скриншоты прикрепите встроенными средствами редактора вопроса. И напишите пару слов о проблеме текстом, пожалуйста. Вдруг кто-то будет искать схожую проблему в поисковике, а поисковики не умеют читать информацию со скриншотов.

Comment: Хорошо, сейчас обновлю

Comment: Начните с этого - [Классы и объекты в C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/classes-and-objects), потом вот это [Пространства имен](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/), и можно еще вот это - [Модификатор `static`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static). А чтобы дать конкретный ответ, нужно найти, а где же у вас статический метод `Player.HasData()`. Вы его не показали.

Comment: А потом, было бы еще не плохо, если бы вы показали в вопросе, какую именно ошибку выдает компилятор. Если вы наведете мышь на подчеркнутое, студия вам покажет, что именно не так. Так же внизу есть вкладка "Ошибки".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так как совершенно не понятно, что делает класс `Player`, и как оно работает, могу только предположить.

Немного подправил код.

```csharp
[ServerEvent(Event.PlayerConnected)]
public void OnPlayerConnected(Player player)
{
    NAPI.Util.ConsoleOutput($"{Player.Name} присоеденился");
    MyServer.Data.Data playerData = new MyServer.Data.Data(player);
    Player.SetData(MyServer.Data.Data.DataIndetifier, playerData);
}
    
[ServerEvent(Event.PlayerSpawn)]
public void OnPlayerSpawn(Player player)
{
    if (Player.HasData(MyServer.Data.Data.DataIndetifier, player))
    {
        var playerData = Player.GetData(MyServer.Data.Data.DataIndetifier, player);
        NAPI.Player.SetPlayerHealth(playerData, 50);
    }
}
```