# Аргументы типа для метода «...» не могут определяться по использованию. Попытайтесь явно определить аргументы типа

Tags: c#

Ребят VS 2019 .NET Core 3.1 выдаёт ошибку:
Аргументы типа для метода "Entity.GetData(string)" не могут определяться по использованию. Попытайтесь явно определить аргументы типа.

Жалуется на GetData => и на SetHealth.

Main.cs

```
    [ServerEvent(Event.PlayerConnected)]
    public void OnPlayerConnected(Player Client)
    {
        Log_Server($"{Client.Name} has connected!");

        Server.Client.Data player = new Server.Client.Data(Client);
        Client.SetData(Server.Client.Data.DataIndentifier, player);
    }

    [ServerEvent(Event.PlayerSpawn)]
    public void OnPlayerSpawn(Player Client)
    {
        if (Client.HasData(Server.Client.Data.DataIndentifier))
        {
            var player = Client.GetData(Server.Client.Data.DataIndentifier);
            player.SetHealth(50);
        }
    }
```

Data.cs

```
class Data
{
    public static readonly String DataIndentifier = "PlayerInfo";
    public Player ClientData { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public int Health { get; set; }

    public Data(Player player)
    {
        this.ClientData = player;
        this.Name = player.Name;
        this.Health = 0;
    }

    public void SetHealth(int health)
    {
        this.Health = health;
        this.ClientData.Health = health;
    }
}
```

Я хз, перерыл весь поисковик и делаю по гайду, но там .NET 2.0 Core. Из за чего ошибка понять не могу. Хотя где то нашёл, что нужно "перейти к определению" и там выделяется такая строка:

```
public T GetData<T>(string key);
```

Comment: Вы какой тип результата ожидаете на выходе метода?

Comment: @tym32167         public void SetHP(int hp)
        {
            this.HP = hp;
            this.ClientData.HP = hp;
        }

Comment: Ну то есть вам нужен int? Тогда GetData<int>(...

Comment: [Что-то мне этот вопрос напоминает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1144941/373567)

Comment: Вот этой функции `Client.GetData`, какого типа вы хотите видеть возвращаемое значение для вашего случая?

Comment: @tym32167 aepot, можно сказать скинул ответ, если не получится исправить скажу.

Comment: @tym32167 вообщем нифига не получилось исправить, только больше ошибок появляется. Сделал более подробный вопрос.

Comment: @aepot Привет, да вопрос тот же, но я исправлял, как там, но всё равно та же ошибка, возможно у него .NET Core 2.0

Comment: Вы пробовали `Client.GetData<int>(Server.Client.Data.DataIndentifier);`?

Comment: @CrazyElf да пробовал, ошибка на GetData пропадает, но появляется:"int" не содержит определения "SetHealth", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "SetHealth", принимающий тип "int" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)

Comment: А, я торможу спросонья. Попробуйте `GetData<Data>`

Comment: Или `GetData<Player>`

Comment: @CrazyElf Ура получился 1 вариант, добавив ещё директиву using Server.Client; Спасибо огромное, я часов 5 убил на это))

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за ответ от [CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/260769/crazyelf). Нужно было исправить на это:

```
var player = Client.GetData<Server.Client.Data>(Server.Client.Data.DataIndentifier);
```

Comment: можно еще в начале кода добавить `using Server` и получится `var player = Client.GetData<Client.Data>(Client.Data.DataIndentifier);`